# Builded Unity game crashes when loading a different scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

During gameplay, I have a menu that comes up once the player finishes a level. However, whenever I click a button that is supposed to take the player to another scene, the game just immediately crashes. Yes, the scene is loaded in the build settings.

Here are some things I've tried:

- Adjusted various build settings
- Preloaded assets that weren't the standard Unity assets
- Changed loading to be asynchronous
- Turned off scripts one-by-one

Here is the crash log that is produced

```
(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)

Unloading 3 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
Crash!!!
SymInit: Symbol-SearchPath: '.;C:\Users\cth25\Desktop\PN;C:\Users\cth25\Desktop\PN;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;SRV*C:\websymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;', symOptions: 534, UserName: 'cth25'
OS-Version: 10.0.0
C:\Users\cth25\Desktop\PN\Project.exe:Project.exe (00007FF75FFA0000), size: 671744 (result: 0), SymType: 'PDB', PDB: '.\WindowsPlayer_x64_Master_mono.pdb', fileVersion: 2018.2.5.29137
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll:ntdll.dll (00007FFBF6F20000), size: 1970176 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.254
C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL:KERNEL32.DLL (00007FFBF46A0000), size: 729088 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll:KERNELBASE.dll (00007FFBF40D0000), size: 2568192 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.165
C:\Users\cth25\Desktop\PN\UnityPlayer.dll:UnityPlayer.dll (00007FFB9A4F0000), size: 23748608 (result: 0), SymType: 'PDB', PDB: '.\UnityPlayer_Win32_x64_mono.pdb', fileVersion: 2018.2.5.29137
C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPT32.dll:CRYPT32.dll (00007FFBF3AF0000), size: 1974272 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPT32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll:ucrtbase.dll (00007FFBF3D00000), size: 1024000 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.254
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WindowsCodecs.dll:WindowsCodecs.dll (00007FFBED5B0000), size: 1761280 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WindowsCodecs.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.285
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\HID.DLL:HID.DLL (00007FFBF1F60000), size: 49152 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\HID.DLL', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSASN1.dll:MSASN1.dll (00007FFBF32B0000), size: 73728 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSASN1.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll:msvcrt.dll (00007FFBF4880000), size: 647168 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll', fileVersion: 7.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll:USER32.dll (00007FFBF4E90000), size: 1638400 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll:RPCRT4.dll (00007FFBF6D90000), size: 1196032 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.112
C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll:win32u.dll (00007FFBF3CE0000), size: 131072 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll:combase.dll (00007FFBF4B50000), size: 3289088 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.112
C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll:GDI32.dll (00007FFBF4670000), size: 163840 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.285
C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll:gdi32full.dll (00007FFBF3E00000), size: 1646592 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.285
C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll:bcryptPrimitives.dll (00007FFBF3FA0000), size: 499712 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.285
C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll:msvcp_win.dll (00007FFBF32F0000), size: 651264 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.137
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll:ole32.dll (00007FFBF6C00000), size: 1380352 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.137
C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll:sechost.dll (00007FFBF4610000), size: 372736 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHLWAPI.dll:SHLWAPI.dll (00007FFBF5480000), size: 331776 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHLWAPI.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll:VERSION.dll (00007FFBF1D30000), size: 40960 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\SETUPAPI.dll:SETUPAPI.dll (00007FFBF5020000), size: 4501504 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\SETUPAPI.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll:cfgmgr32.dll (00007FFBF3390000), size: 299008 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll:ADVAPI32.dll (00007FFBF4AA0000), size: 659456 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll:SHELL32.dll (00007FFBF57C0000), size: 21233664 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.228
C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll:shcore.dll (00007FFBF47D0000), size: 692224 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.112
C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll:windows.storage.dll (00007FFBF33E0000), size: 7393280 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.285
C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll:kernel.appcore.dll (00007FFBF32D0000), size: 69632 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.112
C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll:profapi.dll (00007FFBF3280000), size: 126976 (result: 0), SymType: '-nosymbols-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\powrprof.dll:powrprof.dll (00007FFBF3230000), size: 311296 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\powrprof.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\FLTLIB.DLL:FLTLIB.DLL (00007FFBF32A0000), size: 40960 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\FLTLIB.DLL', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll:WS2_32.dll (00007FFBF4760000), size: 442368 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll:OLEAUT32.dll (00007FFBF5600000), size: 794624 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.48
C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.dll:IMM32.dll (00007FFBF6D60000), size: 184320 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\OPENGL32.dll:OPENGL32.dll (00007FFBBC580000), size: 1179648 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\OPENGL32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll:WINMM.dll (00007FFBF1030000), size: 143360 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINHTTP.dll:WINHTTP.dll (00007FFBEE1F0000), size: 901120 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINHTTP.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.137
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\GLU32.dll:GLU32.dll (00007FFBE1A70000), size: 180224 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\GLU32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll:WINMMBASE.dll (00007FFBF1000000), size: 172032 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll:uxtheme.dll (00007FFBF1330000), size: 622592 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\Users\cth25\Desktop\PN\MonoBleedingEdge\EmbedRuntime\mono-2.0-bdwgc.dll:mono-2.0-bdwgc.dll (00007FFBAA820000), size: 5996544 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Users\cth25\Desktop\PN\MonoBleedingEdge\EmbedRuntime\mono-2.0-bdwgc.dll'
C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL:PSAPI.DLL (00007FFBF4E80000), size: 32768 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSWSOCK.dll:MSWSOCK.dll (00007FFBF2A50000), size: 417792 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSWSOCK.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.DLL:CRYPTBASE.DLL (00007FFBF2C20000), size: 45056 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.DLL', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSCTF.dll:MSCTF.dll (00007FFBF4920000), size: 1527808 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSCTF.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.285
C:\WINDOWS\system32\dwmapi.dll:dwmapi.dll (00007FFBF1590000), size: 167936 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\dwmapi.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\d3d11.dll:d3d11.dll (00007FFBEFB80000), size: 3190784 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\d3d11.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.112
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dxgi.dll:dxgi.dll (00007FFBF20C0000), size: 765952 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dxgi.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.112
C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_ref_pubwu.inf_amd64_708ec8f9a4d134c6\nvldumdx.dll:nvldumdx.dll (00007FFBEB710000), size: 962560 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_ref_pubwu.inf_amd64_708ec8f9a4d134c6\nvldumdx.dll', fileVersion: 23.21.13.9135
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WINTRUST.DLL:WINTRUST.DLL (00007FFBF4350000), size: 356352 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\WINTRUST.DLL', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.81
C:\WINDOWS\System32\imagehlp.dll:imagehlp.dll (00007FFBF6EC0000), size: 118784 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\imagehlp.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll:CRYPTSP.dll (00007FFBF2C00000), size: 94208 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll:rsaenh.dll (00007FFBF2630000), size: 208896 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.254
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll:bcrypt.dll (00007FFBF2D30000), size: 151552 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.112
C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_ref_pubwu.inf_amd64_708ec8f9a4d134c6\nvwgf2umx.dll:nvwgf2umx.dll (00007FFBC09D0000), size: 29392896 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_ref_pubwu.inf_amd64_708ec8f9a4d134c6\nvwgf2umx.dll', fileVersion: 23.21.13.9135
C:\WINDOWS\system32\nvspcap64.dll:nvspcap64.dll (00007FFBC9C70000), size: 2531328 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\nvspcap64.dll', fileVersion: 3.14.0.139
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll:ntmarta.dll (00007FFBF22C0000), size: 200704 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\clbcatq.dll:clbcatq.dll (00007FFBF54E0000), size: 655360 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\clbcatq.dll', fileVersion: 2001.12.10941.16384
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wbemprox.dll:wbemprox.dll (00007FFBED4F0000), size: 69632 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wbemprox.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wbemcomn.dll:wbemcomn.dll (00007FFBEDEF0000), size: 536576 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wbemcomn.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wbemsvc.dll:wbemsvc.dll (00007FFBEB850000), size: 81920 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wbemsvc.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\fastprox.dll:fastprox.dll (00007FFBEC050000), size: 991232 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\fastprox.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\MMDevApi.dll:MMDevApi.dll (00007FFBEE6E0000), size: 483328 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\MMDevApi.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\PROPSYS.dll:PROPSYS.dll (00007FFBF1A30000), size: 1785856 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\PROPSYS.dll', fileVersion: 7.0.17134.112
C:\WINDOWS\System32\DEVOBJ.dll:DEVOBJ.dll (00007FFBF2D60000), size: 159744 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\DEVOBJ.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\AUDIOSES.DLL:AUDIOSES.DLL (00007FFBE27C0000), size: 1228800 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\AUDIOSES.DLL', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.137
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll:wintypes.dll (00007FFBECE50000), size: 1363968 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.112
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\AVRT.dll:AVRT.dll (00007FFBECDC0000), size: 40960 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\AVRT.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.17134.285_none_fb4297e330656775\comctl32.dll:comctl32.dll (00007FFBE30B0000), size: 2527232 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.17134.285_none_fb4297e330656775\comctl32.dll', fileVersion: 6.10.17134.285
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\TextInputFramework.dll:TextInputFramework.dll (00007FFBEB4D0000), size: 618496 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\TextInputFramework.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.191
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CoreUIComponents.dll:CoreUIComponents.dll (00007FFBEC150000), size: 3268608 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CoreUIComponents.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.112
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CoreMessaging.dll:CoreMessaging.dll (00007FFBF08F0000), size: 892928 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CoreMessaging.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.285
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\xinput9_1_0.dll:xinput9_1_0.dll (00007FFBF0090000), size: 28672 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\xinput9_1_0.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL:IPHLPAPI.DLL (00007FFBF27D0000), size: 229376 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\NSI.dll:NSI.dll (00007FFBF5470000), size: 32768 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\NSI.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL:dhcpcsvc6.DLL (00007FFBEEC70000), size: 90112 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL:dhcpcsvc.DLL (00007FFBEE840000), size: 106496 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll:DNSAPI.dll (00007FFBF2810000), size: 778240 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.165
C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll:rasadhlp.dll (00007FFBED950000), size: 40960 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll:dbghelp.dll (00007FFBE3320000), size: 1871872 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll:SspiCli.dll (00007FFBF3160000), size: 196608 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\fwpuclnt.dll:fwpuclnt.dll (00007FFBEFFC0000), size: 466944 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.17134.1

========== OUTPUTTING STACK TRACE ==================

0x00007FFB9A7D5363 (UnityPlayer) GameObject::ActivateAwakeRecursivelyInternal
0x00007FFB9A7D50FB (UnityPlayer) GameObject::ActivateAwakeRecursively
0x00007FFB9A7D5FA9 (UnityPlayer) GameObject::Deactivate
0x00007FFB9A9BD309 (UnityPlayer) DestroyObjectHighLevel
0x00007FFB9A9DE6C8 (UnityPlayer) UnloadGameScene
0x00007FFB9A9E5DA3 (UnityPlayer) LoadSceneOperation::PlayerLoadSceneFromThread
0x00007FFB9A9E4B8B (UnityPlayer) LoadSceneOperation::IntegrateMainThread
0x00007FFB9A9E6D93 (UnityPlayer) PreloadManager::UpdatePreloadingSingleStep
0x00007FFB9A9E7238 (UnityPlayer) PreloadManager::WaitForAllAsyncOperationsToComplete
0x00007FFB9A9E6B16 (UnityPlayer) PreloadManager::UpdatePreloading
0x00007FFB9A9CA4C7 (UnityPlayer) ExecutePlayerLoop
0x00007FFB9A9CA552 (UnityPlayer) ExecutePlayerLoop
0x00007FFB9A9CC41F (UnityPlayer) PlayerLoop
0x00007FFB9B085B35 (UnityPlayer) PerformMainLoop
0x00007FFB9B084C7A (UnityPlayer) MainMessageLoop
0x00007FFB9B08742B (UnityPlayer) UnityMainImpl
0x00007FFB9B0875FB (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FF75FFA1207 (Project) __scrt_common_main_seh
0x00007FFBF46B3034 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFBF6F91461 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart

========== END OF STACKTRACE ===========
```

Scene Change Code:

```
public void BackToMain()
    {
        StartCoroutine(callBack());

    }
IEnumerator callBack()
    {
        AsyncOperation asyncLoad = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(0);



        while (!asyncLoad.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide some of the code that surrounds and includes the scene change code that is crashing?

Comment: I added the code to the main post. Though this code doesn't make much of a difference because when I just use a normal SceneManager.LoadScene, it crashes too.

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerator callBack()
    {
        AsyncOperation asyncLoad = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(0);      

        while (!asyncLoad.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }    
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
```

It seems that this above coroutine will never complete and run into infinity (which will cause Unity to crash) - isDone is complete only when the scene activation is set to true.

To go around this, you can add `asyncLoad.allowSceneActivation = true` and your scene will be automatically enabled when loading is complete.

Otherwise, if you prefer to wait before enabling your scene, you can do the following :

```
 private IEnumerator callBack() {

     AsyncOperation asyncLoad = Application.LoadLevelAsync(0);
     asyncLoad.allowSceneActivation = false;

     while (asyncLoad.progress < 0.9f) {
         yield return null;
     }

     while(!allowLoading) {
         yield return null;
     }

     asyncLoad.allowSceneActivation = true;
 }
```

Then you can set allowLoading to true when convenient.

Here is a complete thread on the subject : https://answers.unity.com/questions/934354/loadlevelasync-stops-at-90.html

Comment: That's a very valid point, but this crash happens when I use a normal SceneManager.LoadScene function as well.

Comment: @CTHoggard is your build a shipping or a development build?

Comment: I think it's a shipping build.